# Infected usb drives in mice

Tags: injection, wireshark

I bought a mouse on aliexpress. It was reasonably cheap. It works well enough to be on par with a mouse I can buy here for 4 times the price. I know, this is a well known business model, and those mice are exactly the same.

Yet being bought here or there, how do I figure out whether there is malicious code being executed at the same time I am using it. F.i. a keylogger being run at the same time from the mouse?

Comment: You are asking about a possible BadUSB device. I think that forest's answer [on this topic](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/206898/199846) can be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BadUSB device functionality](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/206897/badusb-device-functionality)